# How to not check a checkbox when touch

Tags: java, android

I have a checkbox that is switching state on touch. I am wanting to find out how to ignore the state switch on touch. I have an onClickListener attached to the checkbox and inside of that I am changing the state with "Yes" or "No" buttons.

```
        if(sog.isChecked()){
                sog.setChecked(false);
        } else {
                sog.setChecked(true);
        }
```

Edit: The checkbox is switching when touched and my yes button is also changing state.

Edit 2: I want my dialog to change the state rather than the checkbox doing it on it's own.

Edit 3:

```
        sog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(3);

        }
    });

builder.setTitle("Checkbox")
        .setMessage(
                "Are you sure you want to switch checkbox?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int id) {
                        if(sog.isChecked()){
                            sog.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            sog.setChecked(true);
                            setTotalTime();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        return alert;
```

Comment: and what is the problem? it shows an error? it does not do anything? can you post the whole onClickListener?

Comment: android:clickable="false" might help . Then user cannot toggle the checkbox .

Comment: @Matthieu sorry I forgot to add that I will edit.

Comment: You would probably want to look into the onCheckedChangedListener, as opposed to the onClickListner, which in my experience is the convention for Checkboxes: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html. However, I am not sure I entirely understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: So you want a Button controlling the state of a Checkbox, or the other way around?

Comment: I want my dialog to change the state rather than the checkbox doing it on it's own.

Comment: Why are you using a `CheckBox` if you do not want the user to check it? Users will consider your app to be broken when they try to tap the `CheckBox` to change its value and it fails to respond. There are many other ways to let the user know about some state change (e.g., changing text in a `TextView`, changing an icon in an `ImageView`) that would not give the user the impression that your app is broken. Please either let the `CheckBox` work normally or do not use a `CheckBox`.

Comment: @Preethi I added android:clickable="false" but it didn't seem to work. I am wondering if since I added a onClickListener to the button it turned it back on. I am new to Android programming and not sure what takes precedence layouts or code.

Comment: @CommonsWare I do want the checkbox to show it's state. I am just wanting to add a confirmation on changing it from off/on.

Comment: @BryanWilliams what about having a cancel/accept button at the bottom of your activity. Such behaviors are a mess for the user and I am ready to bet a lot you will soon regret a dialog on a checkbox!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am just wanting to add a conformation on changing it from off/on.

Implement an `OnCheckedChangeListener`, registered on the `CheckBox` via `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`. In `onCheckedChanged()`, if the state of the `CheckBox` is one where you want additional confirmation, *leave the `CheckBox` alone* and pop your dialog. If the user taps a button in the dialog indicating that they do not want to make the change, then manually revert the checked state of the `CheckBox` to its prior value.

That being said, I agree with Waza_Be's comment. I am not a fan of "pop the confirmation dialog immediately" sorts of scenarios, though occasionally they are necessary. If there is some other sort of confirmation step as part of this UI (e.g., "save" action bar item), and you want to display a confirmation dialog at that point, that would be better, IMHO.

Comment: That answer does work. I do agree with both of you on popping the confirmation dialog immediately after touching is not a very good user experience. I will move towards a confirm when leaving the activity.

Comment: Great answer. I would like to know can we detect if a checkbox is checked by tap of user or it checked by some programatic script like checkbox.setChecked(true) ?

Comment: @AliAkram: Not easily. I suspect that there is a recipe for doing this by observing touch events.